# Error with math equation

Tags: python

My problem is that if you look at 'support' variable. (In the variable list) it doesn't apply to the  Current Consumption. For EX. If I press 'S' and enter to start the game then press 'M' to display missions then press 'S' to choose the Survivors mission. And I recieve 2 survivors. That count won't add to the support for some reason and display "You are consuming 0.5 blah blah blah" not "You are consuming 0.7 blah blah blah" as it should be adding 0.1 per human? Sorry if this is hard to understand, I'm only 11 trying to program!
    import random
    from PIL import Image

```
print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + 'Zombie Survival Simulator' + '\x1b[0m')
print "Press [S] to start!"
resp = raw_input()
if 's' in resp or 'S' in resp:
    foodmission = ['Convience Store','Grocery Store','Restraunt','Food Storage Area']
    watermission = ['Convience Store', 'Old Gas Station', 'Water Tower','Toppled Coca-Cola truck.']
    survivormission = ['Abandoned Refugee Camp','Bus','Army Camp','Train Station']
    "FOOD"
    #Pick Area
    def pickfoodMission():
        foodmis = random.choice(foodmission)
        return foodmis
    #Chance to get food
    def chanceFood():
        foodcha = random.randint(1,20)
        return foodcha
    #How much food you gain a mission
    def foodPickup():
        foodpick = random.randint(1,2)
        return foodpick
    "WATER"
    #Pick the area
    def pickwaterMission():
        watermis = random.choice(watermission)
        return watermis
    #Chance for getting water
    def chancewater():
        watercha = random.randint(1,20)
        return watercha
    #Number of water you gain a mission
    def waterPickup():
        waterpick = random.randint(1,2)
        return waterpick
    "SURVIVORS"
    #Pick the area
    def picksurvivorMission():
        survivormis = random.choice(survivormission)
        return survivormis
    #Chance for getting water
    def chancehuman():
        humancha = random.randint(1,20)
        return humancha
    #Number of water you gain a mission
    def humanPickup():
        humanpick = random.randint(1,2)
        return humanpick


    food = 3
    water = 3
    human = 5
    healthy = 0
    con = 0.1
    level = 1
    game = 1
    new = 1
    foodcon = 0
    watercon = 0
    support = 0.1 * human
    newhuman = (human + (1 + (human / 5)) + healthy)
    newwater = (water + (1 + (human / 5)) + healthy)
    newfood = (water + (1 + (human / 5)) + healthy)
    while game == 1:
        if food <= 0 or water <= 0:
            print('\x1b[7;30;41m' + 'You and your friends are dead.' + '\33[3m')
            break
        if food >= 3 or water >= 3:
            healthy = healthy + 1
        if food <= 2 or water <= 2:
            healthy = healthy - 1
        print "Current Resources: Food: " +str(food) + " Day(s) Water: " + str(water) + " Day(s)"
        print "Current Survivors " + str(human)
        if healthy <= -3 and healthy >= -1:
            print "Current Survivors are " + ('\x1b[7;30;41m' + 'Nearly Dead' + '\33[3m')
        if healthy == 0:
            print "Current survivors " + ('\x1b[7;30;41m' + 'Are not healthy' + '\33[3m')
        if healthy >= 1 and healthy <= 3:
            print "Current Survivors are " + ('\x1b[7;32;43m' + 'Ok' + '\x1b[0m')
        if healthy >= 3 and healthy <= 5:
            print "Current Survivors are " + ('\x1b[7;32;43m' + 'Great' + '\x1b[0m')
        if healthy >= 5 and healthy <= 7:
            print "Current Survivors are " + ('\x1b[7;32;43m' + 'Excellent' + '\x1b[0m')
        foodcon = support
        watercon = support
        food = food - support
        water = water - support
        print human
        print support
        print "You are consuming " + str(support) + " food and " + str(support) + " water per day"
        if food - support <= 0 or water - support <= 0:
            print('\x1b[7;30;41m' + 'You will not survive the next day.' + '\33[3m')
        print "[M]issions [B]uilding [H]oard [E]nd Day"
        resp = raw_input()
        if 'M' in resp or 'm' in resp:
            print "[F]ood [W]ater [S]urvivor"
            resp = raw_input()
            if 'F' in resp or 'f' in resp:
                foodmis = pickfoodMission()
                print "You go to a " + foodmis
                foodcha = chanceFood()
                if foodcha >= 14:
                    foodpick = foodPickup()
                    food = newfood
                    img = Image.open('food.png')
                    img.show()
                    print('\x1b[7;32;43m' + 'You are now at ' + str(newfood) + ' day(s) of food' + '\x1b[0m')
                elif foodcha < 14:
                    print('\x1b[7;30;41m' + 'You come back empty handed.' + '\x1b[0m')
            elif 'w' in resp or 'W' in resp:
                watermis = pickwaterMission()
                print "You go to a " + watermis
                watercha = chancewater()
                if watercha >= 14:
                    waterpick = waterPickup()
                    water = newwater
                    img = Image.open('water.png')
                    img.show()
                    print('\x1b[7;32;43m' + 'You are now at ' + str(newwater) + ' day(s) of water' + '\x1b[0m')
                elif watercha <= 14:
                    print('\x1b[7;30;41m' + 'You come back empty handed.' + '\x1b[0m')
            elif 's' in resp or 'S' in resp:
               humanmis = picksurvivorMission()
               print "You go to a " + humanmis
               humancha = chancehuman()
               if humancha >= 14:
                    humanpick = humanPickup()
                    human = newhuman
                    print('\x1b[7;32;43m' + 'You are now at ' + str(human) + ' survivor(s)' + '\x1b[0m')
                    img = Image.open('cats.jpg')
                    img.show()
               elif humancha <= 14:
                    print('\x1b[7;30;41m' + 'You come back with no one else new.' + '\x1b[0m')
        if 'B' in resp or 'b' in resp:
            print "[F]ood"
```

Comment: print "You are consuming " + str(support) + " food and " + str(support) + " water per day"   Is the print statement that isn't updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never updating your `support` variable after you set it the first time so each time you print it out it's the same.  Since `support` is dependent on `human`, you should either recalculate `support` every time `human` is updated or have a function like `calculate_support()` which calculates it when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see at a quick glance you are only assigning value to the 'support' variable once in the code:

```
support = 0.1 * human
```

and I don't think this code gets to run again. Once support gets a value through this assignment statement it is not going to update even if you update the value of the 'human' variable.